# Is there a way to reduce Snowflake costs of ingesting Segment.io data?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, segment, cost-management

Our segment.io streams events into our Snowflake instance. This results in the Segment_warehouse being turned on all day and consuming all our credits

Is this a common problem? It's a huge cost add to our operations. Any suggestions to improve this?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with segment.io specifically but is it continuously loading data all day into snowflake?

Comment: Yes. When someone does something in the website for example, we get it near real time. Doesnt seem like you can restrict how often they sync data

Comment: How are you actually loading the data - using Snowpipe? What size warehouse are you using and is it larger than actually required?

Comment: It sounds like you aren't using Snowpipe.  I would look into leveraging that, rather than a warehouse + COPY command.  It will likely save you quite a bit of money, if segment.io can send the data to an S3 bucket instead of loading the data with a warehouse.

Comment: @MikeWalton we are considering doing the S3 route. Otherwise, its a big indirect cost to using segment!

Comment: Your other option would be to batch up the data and load it on a scheduled batch to save on the WH cost.

Comment: Snowpipe is serverless and costs are much less than using a dedicated virtual machine that needs to spin up, underneath Snowpipe is executing a COPY command

Comment: @thedre please can you give us more details about how the data are ingested into Snowflake ? What volume, how often etc. A brief look at the segment website indicates that it does a "sync" either once or twice daily. As such, if there are just two bulk-copy statements executing every day then first of all I would ensure that auto-suspend is switched on for the virtual warehouse you are using - also ensure that you use  a dedicated warehouse for this job.